# ASP.NET App how do to clear Javascript cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, caching

So I changed some jquery on a page in my application and it works fine etc.

But I just noticed that when I push the code to a different server and run the page on that server I need to hit ctrl + f5 to see the changes reflected. Is there a way when doing a code push to clear the cache on that page / javascript so it loads the latest version not the cached version.

Comment: it looks like your browser has cached the .js

Comment: yup thats it, just looking how to get around it

Answer (score 1):

on your referenced javascript file you can add a querystring, like:

```
<script src="/scripts/myfile.js?v=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

whenever you change the text in the file update the query string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at your js files content expiry.

One way to solve this problem is to append a dummy query string parameter to all your *.js urls and set it to the build number of your app or file modified time.

`/Scripts/file.js?v=1.0.12345.0`

This will ensure that each build will use new urls and you can set their content expiry to never.